# Checking a data frame includes other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

In r, if there is a data frame `a1 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4) ,b= c(1,2,3,4))`
, and the other `a2 = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3) ,b= c(1,2,3))`
How can i check that a1 includes a2?

Comment: Can you precisely define what you mean by the statement **a1 includes a2**?

Comment: I meant a1 has all rows of a2 had, and other rows that a2 do not have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nrow(merge(a1, a2, by=c("a","b"))) == nrow(a2)
```

This merges `a2` with `a1`.  The resulting data frame should contain the same number of rows which `a2` has if `a1` contains `a2`.

Comment: Thx, it is really helpful. @Tim Biegeleisen